# AVAudioPlayerNode plays multiple songs simultaneously

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, equalizer, avaudioplayernode

I am trying to develop a music player app with equaliser. I am using `AVAudioEngine` and attaching `AVAudioPlayerNode` but when I change the song the previous song is also playing with the current song. Changing multiple song, plays all the song simultaneously. previously I was using `MPMediaItemPlayer` but in that case I was not able to attach equaliser. I want my app to play one song at a time with equaliser.

```
    self.AVaudioEngine = AVAudioEngine.init()
    self.AVaudioPlayerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode.init()
    self.AVaudioUnitEQ = AVAudioUnitEQ(numberOfBands: 10)
    self.AVaudioEngine.attach(self.AVaudioPlayerNode)
    self.AVaudioEngine.attach(self.AVaudioUnitEQ)

    self.AVaudioPlayerNode.scheduleFile(self.AVaudioFile, at: nil, completionHandler: nil)
    self.AVaudioEngine.connect(self.AVaudioPlayerNode, to: self.AVaudioUnitEQ, format: self.AVaudioFile.processingFormat)
    self.AVaudioEngine.connect(self.AVaudioUnitEQ, to: self.AVaudioEngine.mainMixerNode, format: self.AVaudioFile.processingFormat)

    if !self.AVaudioEngine.isRunning {
        try! self.AVaudioEngine.start()
    }

    let sampleRate = self.AVaudioFile.processingFormat.sampleRate / 2
    let format = self.AVaudioEngine.mainMixerNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
    self.AVaudioEngine.mainMixerNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: AVAudioFrameCount(sampleRate), format: format, block:{ (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer!, time: AVAudioTime!) -> Void in
    })
    self.AVaudioPlayerNode.play()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It`s your code to start playing AVaudioPlayerNode. But, where is your code to stop playing AVaudioPlayerNode?

Have you seen [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayernode)?

Comment: the user selects the song from their tableView to play. this opens the new view controller which is the Music Player. when the user goes back to tableView and selects another song, both songs are playing. I don't want to play the first song after selecting the second song from my tableView cell. Is there any way to stop the player node in a class in which it was not initialized.

Comment: If its a part of business logic then, as a programmer, its your responsibility to track it work. So, you should know what object is playing and stop it if you need it.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I found the answer and I'll post it soon.